# Page numbers in scrreprt KOMA

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering, landscape

I have an scrreprt document where two pages in the middle are in landscape orientation and contain a longtable. I use pdflatex in case it makes a difference.

My code is essentially:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
...
\newpage
\storeareas\myvalues
\KOMAoptions{pagesize, paper=landscape, DIV=20}
\newpage
\begin{longtable}{l}
...
\end{longtable}
\clearpage
\myvalues
\newpage
...
\end{document}
```

Everything is fine except for the page numbers.

On the two landscape pages I have page numbers at the bottom of the long edge of the page, however I would prefer to have them essentially in the same position as on the portrait pages, i.e. at the bottom of the long edge of the page.

How do I achieve this?

After playing around a bit I noticed that this is not due to the longtable but appears in any landscape page. A minimum working example to show this would be:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\storeareas\myvalues
Page numbers are fine here.
\KOMAoptions{pagesize, paper=landscape, DIV=20}
Page numbers are not fine on this page. They should be 90 degrees rotated and centered on the shorter edge of the paper just as on page 1 and 3.
\clearpage
\myvalues
\newpage
\KOMAoptions{pagesize, paper=portrait, DIV=20}
Page numbers are fine here.
\end{document}
```

Still the question remains: How do I get the page numbers to the same position as on the portrait pages?

Comment: the first step is to remove the "essentially" from your question and to show a real example that can be used for tests.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added an example for tests.

Comment: you don't want to reset the page layout, you want to rotate the textbody, and as Simon writes this is done with the landscape enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `\KOMAoptions[paper=landscape]` sets not only the page content but also the header and the footer in landscape mode.
My own setup  (just the essential) ---for a 4 pages longtable, mostly text---,  for keeping the page numbers and headers like in portrait mode is:

```
\afterpage{% \RequirePackage{afterpage} %causes the commands specified in its argument to be expanded after the current page is output
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)

\pdfbookmark[2]{Title for pdf bookmarks}{sec:D1}

       \tolerance=1 % no hyphenation
       \emergencystretch=\maxdimen
       \hyphenpenalty=10000
       \hbadness=10000  
    
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page  \RequirePackage{pdflscape} %PDF support to the environment landscape
    \footnotesize

    \legend{\Large Caption of the table} \label{D1} 
\vspace{-15pt}

  \begin{center}    
        \begin{longtable}{m{200pt}m{3pt}m{20pt}m{240pt}}    
            
                \toprule
            .... & ... &... & ...\\  %column titles
            \endfirsthead
            
            \multicolumn{4}{r}      {\footnotesize \emph{ \ldots{} from previous page.}} \\
            \toprule
            .... & ... &... & ...\\  %column titles
             \midrule 
            \endhead
            
            \multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize \emph{Continued on the next page \ldots{} }} \\
            \endfoot
            %       \bottomrule
            
            \endlastfoot                
            
            \midrule
             .... & ... & .... & ... \\ 
             .... & ... & .... & ... \\ 
             .... & ... & .... & ... \\ 
             .... & ... & .... & ... \\ 
                etc
                
             \bottomrule        
        \end{longtable}%    
     \end{center}   
   \end{landscape}%
\clearpage
}
```

See page 417, chap 16 of The Guide KOMA-Script (2020). Please provide a MWE so see and try your full configuration.

**UPDATE**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\RequirePackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
    
\newpage
\storeareas\myvalues
Page numbers are fine here.
%\KOMAoptions{pagesize, paper=landscape, DIV=20}

\begin{landscape}
Page numbers now are FINE on this page. They should be 90 degrees rotated and centered on the shorter edge of the paper just as on page 1 and 3.
\end{landscape}

\clearpage
%\myvalues
%\newpage
\KOMAoptions{pagesize, paper=portrait, DIV=20}
Page numbers are fine here.
\end{document}
```

[image: fine]

Now the page number 2 is located in same place than #1 and #2. This is fine for screen reading

If the document is going to be printed pehaps  the rotating alternative is better.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\RequirePackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\storeareas\myvalues
Page numbers are fine here.
%\KOMAoptions{pagesize, paper=landscape, DIV=20}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
Page numbers now are FINE on this page. They are 90 degrees rotated and centered on the shorter edge of the paper just as 
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\clearpage
%\myvalues
%\newpage
\KOMAoptions{pagesize, paper=portrait, DIV=20}
Page numbers are fine here.
\end{document}
```

[image: alt]

Comment: So you are saying that I cannot do this with KOMAoptions, but have to use \begin{landscape}\end{landscape}?

Comment: This is what the chap 16 of The Guide KOMA-Script  says. Why do not try the alternative ?

Comment: Please the updated answer.

Comment: Page numbers are fine, however the page got smaller breaking the longtable compared to the version with KOMAoptions. How can I increase the height (=shorter length) of the landscape pages?

Comment: I would need an example of the longtable you are using to asses the issue. Or may be you could ask another, more specific,  question. `Longtable` it is its own theme.